# helm upgrade -- install doesn't work correctly

Tags: kubernetes, installation, upgrade, kubernetes-helm

I am facing a problem during the upgrade of my release, it is happening that in case I have a release

(example-release contains a list of services...)

```
Release                                Version
example-release                         0.0.2


example-release service list:
   service1, version 1.1
```

When I try to upgrade the release with a new chart containing a different version of a service:

```
helm upgrade --install example-release release-0.0.1.tgz
example-release service list:
   service1, version 1.0
```

it doesn't remove and reinstall the impacted service to downgrade.

Instead if I execute the following command, it is forced to install:

```
helm upgrade --install --force example-release release-0.0.1.tgz
```

Then the service is **reinstalled**.
To notice that by executing :

```
 helm upgrade example-release release-0.0.1.tgz
```

I don't see any errors, even if the impacted service to downgrade is not touched.

How **--force** realizes that there is a problem ??

If during an upgrade we install a configmap, should the upgrade to the previous version remove that configmap?

*Small update:*
Removing the whole release and installing from scratch the upgrade(upgrade/downgrade) of my helm release started to work again without --force, so it sounds like a bug?!? I don't know !

thanks

Comment: After you do the `helm upgrade`, what specifically do you see in the cluster (things like `helm list` and `kubectl describe deployment` outputs); why do you think the downgrade didn't happen?  Helm will try to update things in-place if it can, but this can result in things like updating ConfigMap contents and not restarting the associated pods.

Comment: hi @DavidMaze, I have used : helm history example-release to verify that the upgrade has been performed and kubectl describe pod name to verify that the service has taken the correct image version